# Prove: If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ if and only if $ab \mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$ is $1$ and the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$ must be $ab$.

We also know that for some integers $x$ and $y$, $ax = c$ and $by = c$.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious that if $ab | c$ then $a|c$ and $b|c$.

On the other hand, if $(a,b) = 1$ and $ax = c$ , $by=c$, then $ax=by$.

Claim: $b  | x$.

Proof: Since $(a,b) = 1$, by Bezout's theorem, there exist integers $m,n$ such that $am+bn=1$. Now, multiply by $x$ on both sides, and you see that $axm+bnx=x$, or $bym+bnx=x$, or $b(my+nx) = x$, so  that $b | x$.

Hence, if $bf = x$, then $abf=c$, so $ab | c$. Hence, we are done, and $a|c \wedge b | c \iff ab | c$.

Comment: @Laina I was worried that you wanted only a hint, not the whole answer. You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then their lowest common multiple is $ab$.

The lowest common multiple divides any common multiple.