# If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ and $ab \leq c$, is it true that $ab \mid c$?

Tags: number-theory

For $a,b,c \in N$, if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ and $ab \leq c$, is it true that $ab \mid c$ ? I think it is true but i do not know how to show this. Also, $gcd(a,b)$ may or may not be 1.

EDIT: $a$ and $b$ are distinct.

Comment: hint: let $a=b=2$, and $c=6$. if however $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then the answer is yes, and there's no need to add the hypothesis $ab\leqslant c$ in that case

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom what if $a,b$ are distinct ?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I should have added that condition in also.

Comment: Just having $a\neq b$ and $ab\leq c$ is not enough; 2 and 4 both divide 12 but 8 does not.

Comment: Many counterexamples can be found easily if $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$.  A better Question would have researched that and focused on the case $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, which has been [asked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983972/prove-if-a-and-b-are-relatively-prime-then-a-mid-c-and-b-mid-c-if-an) many times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true.

Take for example, $$a=4, b=6, c=36$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $c= 2^5 3^4 = 2592$ and $a = 2^4 =16$ and $b=2^43 = 48$ then $ab = 768 <c$ but $768 \nmid 2592$